# Remove Chromium Sync Data from Google account

Tags: google-account, synchronization

I want to sign in to a new installation of Chromium with a Google account, but I don't want any previously synced data to be downloaded to the browser. How can I delete this data from my Google account?

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome Sync options](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync) under [Google Account Settings](http://accounts.google.com) has an option to clear Chrome sync data.

[image]

Comment: Is it the same for Google Chrome and Chromium?